# C#: What's the different between UseSerilog and assigning Log.Logger?

Tags: c#, serilog

I want to use my services to perform an async call, generate a parameter to pass to my serilog config before booting up and logging.

What is the difference?

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .WriteTo.Console()
);
```

Second:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

If I just set Log.Logger to my custom sink later on in the flow (once services are registered), will it be equivalent to setting it inside UseSerilog?

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/ discusses this in detail - HTH